# Javascript/Jquery - Target closest relevant block to show content in a stream of similar cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of cards. Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vfremdso/).
even if i only put 3 cards in the demo i have an infinite number if cards in the real app.

When you hover on the first card, and then click on the "plus" icon that appears, a block of info covers the whole card and show info specific to this card. 
What I don't manage to do is: when a user clicks on the "plus "icon of any card, like the second, third ...the user should see the info of this card appear (just like it does for the first card).

**Constraint:**

I could indeed put a number for each card like id "#card345", "#card567" and so on, and use javascript to put this variable id inside the javascript script to only target this id number.
For performance reasons, I would like not to do it this way, **that is to say not use any VARIABLE such as the id of the card inside the javascript code**. and only use a jquery/javascript code to target the "closest" block to show. I heard of "closest" or next() but I don't manage to do it. I'm open to any css or javascript/jquery solution.

**Code**

HTML

```
<div class="center jumbotron">

<div id="deal-zone">
<ul class="cards-list">

  <li class="card 353">      

    <div class="card-content">        

   <div id="info-overlay">
    <div class="close-overlay">
              <a>close</a>
              </div>
              some info some longer info and this is really long now i wonder how long it can get

   </div>

      <div class="card-image">        
        <a href="/operations/thisiscool"></a>
          <figure>
          <a href="/operations/thisiscool">            
            <img style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="HPImageBanner_353" src="http://vp-eu.scene7.com/is/image/vpeu/0/00_54093_FR_brandvisualnbrandvisualfr">           

            <!-- operation card's short details on 2-column view-->
            </a>
            <figcaption id="tek" class="card-short-info">
              <a href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111"></a>
              <a class="moreInfo" id="BtnHomeOperationExpand_5331345" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">

                <i id="plusbutton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_353"></i>
               </a>            

              <div class="short-info-content">               
                <a id="dateSales_53120" class="dateSales _saleLink" href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111">Jusqu'au <span class="outstandingwords">12 novembrex</span></a>                      
              </div>



            </figcaption>
          </figure>        
      </div>

    </div> 
       <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse left-aligned" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="infoSales">
                <a id="info" class="moreInfo"></a>
                this is the big details i want                
            </div>

      </div>


  </li>
 <!-- cards in the stream of deal -->

 <li class="card 354">      

    <div class="card-content">        
   <div id="info-overlay">
    <div class="close-overlay">
              <a>close</a>
              </div>
              some info some longer info and this is really long now i wonder how long it can get

              </div>
      <div class="card-image">        
        <a href="/operations/thisiscool"></a>
          <figure>
          <a href="/operations/thisiscool">            
            <img style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="HPImageBanner_353" src="http://vp-eu.scene7.com/is/image/vpeu/5/00_51449_FR_brandvisualnbrandvisualfr">           

            <!-- operation card's short details on 2-column view-->
            </a>
            <figcaption id="tek" class="card-short-info">
              <a href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111"></a>
              <a class="moreInfo" id="BtnHomeOperationExpand_5331345" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">

                <i id="plusbutton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_353"></i>
               </a>            

              <div class="short-info-content">               
                <a id="dateSales_53120" class="dateSales _saleLink" href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111">Jusqu'au <span class="outstandingwords">12 novembrex</span></a>                      
              </div>



            </figcaption>
          </figure>        
      </div>

    </div> 
       <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse left-aligned" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="infoSales">
                <a id="info" class="moreInfo"></a>
                this is the big details for the second card number  i want                
            </div>

      </div>


  </li>

  <li class="card 355">      

    <div class="card-content">        
   <div id="info-overlay">
    <div class="close-overlay">
              <a>close</a>
              </div>
              some info some longer info and this is really long now i wonder how long it can get

              </div>
      <div class="card-image">        
        <a href="/operations/thisiscool"></a>
          <figure>
          <a href="/operations/thisiscool">            
            <img style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="HPImageBanner_353" src="http://vp-eu.scene7.com/is/image/vpeu/1/00_53818_FR_brandvisualnbrandvisualfr">           

            <!-- operation card's short details on 2-column view-->
            </a>
            <figcaption id="tek" class="card-short-info">
              <a href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111"></a>
              <a class="moreInfo" id="BtnHomeOperationExpand_5331345" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">

                <i id="plusbutton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_353"></i>
               </a>            

              <div class="short-info-content">               
                <a id="dateSales_53120" class="dateSales _saleLink" href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111">Jusqu'au <span class="outstandingwords">12 novembrex</span></a>                      
              </div>



            </figcaption>
          </figure>        
      </div>

    </div> 
       <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse left-aligned" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="infoSales">
                <a id="info" class="moreInfo"></a>
                this is the big details for the THIRd card i want                
            </div>

      </div>


  </li>
</ul>


  </div>

  </div>
```

CSS

```
#info-overlay {
  display:none;
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:grey;
}

.close-overlay {
  float:right;
  padding:5px;
}


#deal-zone {
  margin-top: 20px;  
}
#deal-zone ul {
    padding: 0;
  }
.cards-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
.card {
    width: 47%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1% 21px 1%;
}
.card-content {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.card-image {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 33.88%;

}
.card-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: red; 
  }

.container .jumbotron {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.card-short-info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 13%;
  position: absolute; 
  color: #464650;
  padding: 0px 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom:0; 
  display: none;    
}
.moreInfo {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  float: right; 
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #464650;
}
.short-info-content {
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: left;  
}
.card-short-info a.dateSales {
  color: #464650;
}

.card-long-info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; 
  color: #464650;
  padding: 0px 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom:0; 
  display: none;    
}
```

JS

```
$(".card-image").hoverIntent({
            sensitivity:100,//sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
            interval:100,//milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
            timeout:100,//milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
            over:function(){
              $('.card-short-info',this).slideToggle(100);
            },
            out:function(){
              $('.card-short-info',this).slideToggle(300);


            }
        });

$(".close-overlay").click(function(){
      $("#info-overlay").hide();

});

$("#plusbutton").click(function(){

  $("#info-overlay").show();

});
```

Comment: I think this is because of using multiple `plusbutton` ids.

Comment: yea I know. how to show only the relevamt card info on an infinite nb if cards is the purpose of my question

Comment: it should work no matter the number of cards displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID of an element must be unique, so use `info-overlay` and `plusbutton` as classes

```js
$(".card-image").hoverIntent({
  sensitivity: 100, //sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
  interval: 100, //milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
  timeout: 100, //milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
  over: function() {
    $('.card-short-info', this).slideToggle(100);
  },
  out: function() {
    $('.card-short-info', this).slideToggle(300);


  }
});

$(".close-overlay").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.card-content').find(".info-overlay").hide();
});

$(".plusbutton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.card-content').find(".info-overlay").show();
});
```

```css
    .info-overlay {
      display: none;
      z-index: 999;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    .close-overlay {
      float: right;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    #deal-zone {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    #deal-zone ul {
      padding: 0;
    }
    .cards-list {
      list-style: none;
      display: block;
      height: auto;
    }
    .card {
      width: 47%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 1% 21px 1%;
    }
    .card-content {
      background: #fff;
      position: relative;
    }
    .card-image {
      vertical-align: top;
      position: relative;
      line-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-bottom: 33.88%;
    }
    .card-image img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      color: red;
    }
    .container .jumbotron {
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
    }
    .card-short-info {
      width: 100%;
      height: 13%;
      position: absolute;
      color: #464650;
      padding: 0px 1em;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      background-color: grey;
      bottom: 0;
      display: none;
    }
    .moreInfo {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      float: right;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: normal;
      color: #464650;
    }
    .short-info-content {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      text-align: left;
    }
    .card-short-info a.dateSales {
      color: #464650;
    }
    .card-long-info {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      color: #464650;
      padding: 0px 1em;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      background-color: grey;
      bottom: 0;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.hoverintent/1.8.1/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
<div class="center jumbotron">

  <div id="deal-zone">
    <ul class="cards-list">

      <li class="card 353">

        <div class="card-content">

          <div class="info-overlay">
            <div class="close-overlay">
              <a>close</a>
            </div>
            some info some longer info and this is really long now i wonder how long it can get

          </div>

          <div class="card-image">
            <a href="/operations/thisiscool"></a>
            <figure>
              <a href="/operations/thisiscool">
                <img style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="HPImageBanner_353" src="http://vp-eu.scene7.com/is/image/vpeu/0/00_54093_FR_brandvisualnbrandvisualfr">

                <!-- operation card's short details on 2-column view-->
              </a>
              <figcaption id="tek" class="card-short-info">
                <a href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111"></a>
                <a class="moreInfo" id="BtnHomeOperationExpand_5331345" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">

                  <i class="plusbutton glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_353"></i>
                </a>

                <div class="short-info-content">
                  <a id="dateSales_53120" class="dateSales _saleLink" href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111">Jusqu'au <span class="outstandingwords">12 novembrex</span></a>
                </div>



              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse left-aligned" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="infoSales">
            <a id="info" class="moreInfo"></a>
            this is the big details i want
          </div>

        </div>


      </li>
      <!-- cards in the stream of deal -->

      <li class="card 354">

        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="info-overlay">
            <div class="close-overlay">
              <a>close</a>
            </div>
            some info some longer info and this is really long now i wonder how long it can get

          </div>
          <div class="card-image">
            <a href="/operations/thisiscool"></a>
            <figure>
              <a href="/operations/thisiscool">
                <img style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="HPImageBanner_353" src="http://vp-eu.scene7.com/is/image/vpeu/5/00_51449_FR_brandvisualnbrandvisualfr">

                <!-- operation card's short details on 2-column view-->
              </a>
              <figcaption id="tek" class="card-short-info">
                <a href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111"></a>
                <a class="moreInfo" id="BtnHomeOperationExpand_5331345" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">

                  <i class="plusbutton glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_353"></i>
                </a>

                <div class="short-info-content">
                  <a id="dateSales_53120" class="dateSales _saleLink" href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111">Jusqu'au <span class="outstandingwords">12 novembrex</span></a>
                </div>



              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse left-aligned" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="infoSales">
            <a id="info" class="moreInfo"></a>
            this is the big details for the second card number i want
          </div>

        </div>


      </li>

      <li class="card 355">

        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="info-overlay">
            <div class="close-overlay">
              <a>close</a>
            </div>
            some info some longer info and this is really long now i wonder how long it can get

          </div>
          <div class="card-image">
            <a href="/operations/thisiscool"></a>
            <figure>
              <a href="/operations/thisiscool">
                <img style="opacity: 1; display: block;" id="HPImageBanner_353" src="http://vp-eu.scene7.com/is/image/vpeu/1/00_53818_FR_brandvisualnbrandvisualfr">

                <!-- operation card's short details on 2-column view-->
              </a>
              <figcaption id="tek" class="card-short-info">
                <a href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111"></a>
                <a class="moreInfo" id="BtnHomeOperationExpand_5331345" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">

                  <i class="plusbutton glyphicon glyphicon-plus detail-icon_353"></i>
                </a>

                <div class="short-info-content">
                  <a id="dateSales_53120" class="dateSales _saleLink" href="/operations/la-semaine-de-la-beaute-a-paris-111">Jusqu'au <span class="outstandingwords">12 novembrex</span></a>
                </div>



              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse left-aligned" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="infoSales">
            <a id="info" class="moreInfo"></a>
            this is the big details for the THIRd card i want
          </div>

        </div>


      </li>
    </ul>


  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the closest() function?

[Here's](http://Here's%20the%20docs.) the docs.

Something like

```
$("#plusbutton").click(function(e){
   $(e.target).closest('.card').find('.info-overlay').show();
}
```

And beside the code, I would strongly suggest you not to use IDS, use classes instead for elements names, since they're not unique.

Also, for the opposite reason, do not use the card ID as a class: use an ID here (if you really need the card ID). And remember that you shouldn't use only the number. Better something like: `id="card-353"`

Take a look:

https://jsfiddle.net/58Ltod03/4/

I've just edited your fiddle, if I understand your question, now it works properly.

Still, please clean up your html code :)